# What does this PowerShell code do?

Tags: powershell

I found the following code in a book about PowerShell scripts:

```
$Text = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input your text'

function FastTrain($text) {
    $h = @{}

    ForEach ($word in [regex]::split($text.ToLower(), '\W+'))
    {
        $h[$word] = ''
    }

    $h
}

FastTrain($Text)
```

I tried to run it, and got this: [image]

What does it do? I think that it gets a string from the user, and then searches for characters, but I am not entirely sure.

Answer (score 2):

1. Read a line of text from the user

   ```
   $Text = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input your text'
   ```
2. Define a function

   ```
   function FastTrain($text) {
   ```

   - Create a new hashtable. This is a data structure that maps keys to values.

     ```
     $h = @{}
     ```
   - Lower-case the text argument and split it on successive non-word characters. This results in an array of “words” (however, since “word” characters for regular expressions are a quite arbitrary concept of little use anywhere, this will also include numbers, underscores, and a bunch of other things apart from letters).

     ```
     ForEach ($word in [regex]::split($text.ToLower(), '\W+'))
     {
     ```
   - Use the word as key in the hashtable and set the value to an empty string. This is merely a poor-man's version of a set, so the hashtable will contain all *unique* words from the input as keys (the values are irrelevant).

     ```
        $h[$word] = ''
     }
     ```
   - Return the hashtable

     ```
         $h
     }
     ```
3. Run above function on the input read earlier. This will also cause the hashtable from earlier to be printed on the screen since any object that is returned from a statement or pipeline will be output by default.

   ```
   FastTrain($Text)
   ```

   Note that this usage of PowerShell functions is technically incorrect and can easily lead to mistakes. A PowerShell function is invoked like any other PowerShell command, but *not* like a .NET method. So arguments are separated by spaces and there are no parentheses. In this case it works because there is only a single argument.

Given how atrocious this example is, I guess you should find a better book. This code looks nothing like how PowerShell code *should* look (in my opinion at least). The function performed by that code is essentially “Given a string, return all unique words from it”. A more PowerShell-ey version of that function would probably be:

```
function Get-UniqueWords($Text) {
  $Text.ToLower() -split '\W+' | Select -Unique
}
```

No messing around with a hashtable, just to get a set of sorts. No unnecessary call to a .NET method where a PowerShell operator suffices. And using the pipeline to transform and/or filter a stream of data. Loops like that are often unnecessary since the pipeline is often easier to read and grasp (since you can just read how things are piped into another, instead of having to parse what happens to data structures to find out what happens to your data).

However, considering my gripe about `\w`/`\W` from earlier, the following regex would probably yield saner results for humans:

```
function Get-UniqueWords($Text) {
  $Text.ToLower() -split '\P{L}+' | Select -Unique
}
```

This really only considers letters.

Answer (score 0):

It is reading a sentence from the user:

```
$Text = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input your text'
```

It then creates an empty hashtable (a collection of key-value pairs):

```
$h = @{}
```

Then, splits the sentence into words:

```
[regex]::split($text.ToLower(), '\W+'))
```

And adds each one to the hashtable (with the word as the key, and nothing for the value):

```
$h[$word] = ''
```

Finally, it prints the hashtable:

```
$h
```

There is a function definition/call mixed in, but the above is what the code does.